# Cardinality and Elements of a Quotient Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm stuck in the computation of the isomorphism that gives:
 $$\mathbb{Z}/(7)\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}/(21)}{(7)/(21)}$$ where $(a)$ denotes the ideal (aka $\mathbb{Z}$-module) generated by the integer $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the fraction of the right side is a quotient $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

> What is the cardinality of $(7)/(21)$, how is it computed, which are its elements?

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: I am confused as to what all you are asking. Mainly, I am not sure whether you know that the isomorphism is true?

Comment: Hi, I know the proof of the existance of this isomorphism, and I'm trying to construct it explicitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing out the elements explicitly, $$ (7) = \{ -14, -7, 0 , 7 , 14, 21, \cdots \}$$ and $$ (21) = \{ -21, 0 , 21, 42, \cdots \}.$$ Consider what the elements of $(7)$ are modulo $(21).$ Some examples: $$-14 + (21) = 7 + (21), \ \ \ -7+(21) = 14+(21).$$

In general, all the residues of $(7)$ modulo $(21)$ are $$ \frac{(7)}{(21)} = \{ 0+(21), 7+(21), 14+(21)\}.$$

So $\dfrac{(7)}{(21)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$ by the isomorphism $\phi(7n+(21)) = n\mod 3.$ Check this is infact an isomorphism.

Now consider $$\mathbb{Z}/(21)=\{ 0+(21), 1+(21), \cdots, \ 20+(21)\}.$$

So computing its residues modulo $(7)/(21)$ (which we computed above) we see $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}/(21)}{(7)/(21)} = \left\{ 0+(21) + \frac{(7)}{(21)}, 1+ (21)+\frac{(7)}{(21)}, \cdots, \  6+(21)+\frac{(7)}{(21)} \right\}.$$

Just take a look at the elements on the right hand side, I'm sure you can suspect how that group behaves - just like $\mathbb{Z}/(7),$ since the extra $(21)+\dfrac{(7)}{(21)}$ terms are just kind of "tagged along" in the arithmetic. So one strongly suspects that $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}/(21)}{(7)/(21)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(7)$$ by the isomorphism $$\varphi\left(n+ (21)+\dfrac{(7)}{(21)}\right) = n\mod 7.$$ You should check for yourself that this is indeed an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! i had trouble understanding  $$ \frac{(7)}{(21)} = \{ 0+(21), 7+(21), 14+(21)\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3.$$ and  $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}/(21)}{(7)/(21)} = \left\{ 0+(21) + \frac{(7)}{(21)}, 1+ (21)+\frac{(7)}{(21)}, \cdots, \  6+(21)+\frac{(7)}{(21)} \right\}.$$

Comment: Does the isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ has something to do with $21/7=3$? Is there fromula, algorithm or result to compute $$ \# \left(\frac{(a)}{(b)}\right)$$ for arbitrary $ a, b \in X $, elements of an arbitrary module or ring?

Comment: @dktr.k1 Do you understand how I reached $ \dfrac{(7)}{(21)} = \{ 0 + (21), 7+(21), 14+(21) \}?$ If you can get up to there, then seeing that $ (7)/(21) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$ is a matter of getting your hands dirty and looking at how the elements in the group really behave. Add some of the elements together, find out their inverses, their orders, convince yourself that this group is really behaving like how $\mathbb{Z}_3$ behaves and then check that with the isomorphism I wrote.

Comment: yes I got it all :) I actually had the three equivalnt classes before posting, but written down differently, with the $\bar{x}$ notation. so it was difficult to know the congruency terms that i was "carrying" in the disguised $\mathbb{Z}_7$...my trouble was before reading your answer. thank you.

Comment: ...and yes, i will do now the operation tables to beat that down. what about my question above? is this the so called "index of an abelian group in another group"?